# How can I retrieve the file name defined inside this string? the filename is after _ character and before * character of my string

Tags: javascript

I have an URL of an images like this:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project/o/attachments%2F1610905935653_gatto.jpg?alt=media&token=a89b3cbb-d1cd-4310-b2f3-23395db50033

This URL contains the image name that in this particualr case it is:**gatto.jpg**

What could be a smart way to extract the name from a string like the previous one representing my URL.

Consider the case that this URL is defined itno a string named **url**

```
let url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project/o/attachments%2F1610905935653_gatto.jpg?alt=media&token=a89b3cbb-d1cd-4310-b2f3-23395db50033"
```

So I have to extract what is after the **_** character and what it is before the **?** character.

What can be a smart solution to achieve this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I'm not too familiar with RegEx I would just split the string twice, since you have only one "_" and one "?" In your URL, I would first split the URL based on "?" and then take the first element and split that again based on "_"

```js
var url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project/o/attachments%2F1610905935653_gatto.jpg?alt=media&token=a89b3cbb-d1cd-4310-b2f3-23395db50033";
var filename = url.split("?")[0].split("_")[1];
```

Of course you can always look up the RegEx for that as well.

Comment: You can use lookaheads and lookbehinds to achieve this with a regular expression. `(?<=_)[\w\.]+(?=\?)` will capture alphanumeric characters, underscores, and periods between your delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) to parse the path and split it to get the filename:

```js
let url = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/my-project/o/attachments%2F1610905935653_gatto.jpg?alt=media&token=a89b3cbb-d1cd-4310-b2f3-23395db50033";

url = decodeURIComponent(url);
const fileName = new URL(url).pathname.split("/").pop().split("_").pop();

//Use fileName as required
console.log(fileName);
```